# Uncaught TypeError: this.movie.setSheetName is not a function - Angularjs Datatable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

Could someone let me know why am i getting this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.movie.setSheetName is not a function

While using the buttons in Angularjs Datatable mentioned here

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withButtons

Here is the code

```
$rootScope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withDisplayLength(10)
    .withDOM('frtip')
    .withBootstrap()
    .withBootstrapOptions({
        TableTools: {
            classes: {
            container: 'btn-group',
                buttons: {
                    normal: 'btn btn-danger'
                }
            }
        },
        ColVis: {
            classes: {
                masterButton: 'btn btn-primary'
            }
        },
        pagination: {
            classes: {
                ul: 'pagination pagination-sm'
            }
        }
    })
    .withOption('bLengthChange', false).withButtons([
        'copy',
        'print',
        'excel'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have [**jszip**](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) installed. Include this line to your `bower.json` `dependencies` section (if you are using bower)

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "jszip": "2.6.0" 
}
```

and run a `bower update`. Or use `npm` :

```
npm install jszip@2.6.0
```

It is important that you are specific about using `2.6.0` (or lower). dataTables is not compatible with the latest `3.0.0`.

---

Update; setting the filename :

```
.withButtons([ 
    { 
      extend : 'excel'
      filename: 'download', 
    },
    ...
])
```

This will result in a file named `download.xlsx`

Comment: after adding this, it is saving the data as blob object .xlsx but not with any file name

Comment: @Yahiya, just specify a filename as well - see update.

Comment: Superb !! one last question though. I see the file is saved with say 210 Kb but when i open the file its empty. I am on linux mint with open office

Comment: @Yahiya, I dont know. Using linux and LibreOffice myself, have no problems with Excel, CSV, PDF or similar.  Try using `extend: 'excelHtml5'` instead of `extend: 'excel'`. `'excel'` is actually a "fallback" to use the flash-version if available. Otherwise, the only known problem with excel is with Safari due to an webkit error (see [*'docs**](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5))

Comment: dint work. may be some issue with openoffice, but anyway,  your answers helped me and now am able to save the files. Thank you @davidkonrad.